# Can't remove a strange element from menu on wordpress template

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to remove some weird separators between each of my menu elements.
When I inspect the code, those are shown as circles into a box character.

Please if someone knows how to remove them!

Thanks in advance

[Screenshot from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clOfF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [Whitespace-only text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#Whitespace-only_text_nodes).

Firefox renders line-breaks between nodes as this symbol of a dot inside a square.

> Since Firefox 52, the Inspector displays these whitespace nodes, so
>   you can see where the gaps in your markup come from. Whitespace nodes
>   are represented with a dot:  and you get an explanatory tooltip when
>   you hover over them